# JOGL Texture problems

Tags: opengl, 3d, textures, jogl, bufferedimage

I'm in the process of trying to learn JOGL bindings. The tutorials seem to be outdated, so I'm always trying to piece together what is valid from each one.

I'm having problems trying to apply a simple texture to a square plane.

I have an image that is 204 X 204 called box.png.

In my init() I do the following to get the texture loaded:

```
        try {
            InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("box.png");
            TextureData data = TextureIO.newTextureData(gl.getGLProfile(),
                stream, 100, 200, false, "png");
            boxTexture = TextureIO.newTexture(data);
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

Then I try to apply my texture doing the following in my display():

```
        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        boxTexture.enable(gl);
        boxTexture.bind(gl);

        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
        // Front Face
        gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
        gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
        gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
        gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        gl.glEnd();
```

Are there any blaring problems that would explain why I'm failing?

Answer (score 2):

Only thing I can think of is that the texture isn't a power of 2.  Change the size of the texture to 256x256 and see if it works then.  Depending on your graphics card, it will or won't be supported (it should be if the card isn't ancient).